# Caching values inside a Javascript function

Tags: javascript

I have a simple Javascript method (member function of an object) which keeps an internal cache (to avoid unnecessary ajax requests.)

I must be confused about Javascript scope rules or something because updates to the cache don't seem to be visible if they're made from within a nested function.

For example:

```
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || { };
window.mynamespace.foo = function()
{
    this.cache = this.cache || { };

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.cache));

    this.cache["foo"] = "bar";
}
```

Here's a simple example that is meant to demonstrate that items inserted into the cache are being remembered across calls to `mynamespace.foo()`.

In my `onload` or `$(document).ready()` handler, if I say:

```
window.mynamespace.foo();
window.mynamespace.foo();
```

I get two alerts, where the first shows me `{}` and the second shows me `{"foo" : "bar"}`.  Okay great, that's **exactly** what I expected.  So my cache seems to work.

*But*... if I try to update the cache from within a *nested* function (specifically within a callback handler of some async operation), the updates to my cache don't seem to propagate.

For example:

```
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || { };

window.mynamespace.foo = function()
{
    var instance = this;

    this.cache = this.cache || { };

    alert(JSON.stringify(this.cache));

    window.setTimeout(
        function()
        {
            instance.cache["foo"] = "bar";
        },
        0
    );
}
```

Here, I update the cache from within a nested function (a callback handler for `window.setTimeout`).

In this case, if I call `window.mynamespace.foo()` twice from within my document `onload` handler, I get two alerts, each showing me `{}` - an empty object.  So now my cache is *not* updating.

Okay, so something about my understanding of Javascript scoping rules here is broken.  I realize that `this` means something different from within a nested function, which is why I specifically use the `instance` variable which always refers to the `window.mynamespace.foo` object.

Please educate me about my error here.

Comment: `setTimeout` code runs **in the future**. So of course the second alert shows an empty object, because the cache has not been modified **yet**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note this is not a problem of scoping or nested functions, because the following code works:

```js
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {
  cache: {},
  foo: function() {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.cache));
    (function() {
      window.mynamespace.cache["foo"] = "bar";
    })();
  }
};
window.mynamespace.foo();
window.mynamespace.foo();
```

The problem is that `setTimeout` code runs **in the future**. So of course the second alert shows an empty object, because the cache has not been modified **yet**.

Therefore, if you really need to update the cache asynchronously, you can use callbacks:

```js
window.mynamespace = window.mynamespace || {
  cache: {},
  foo: function(callback) {
    alert(JSON.stringify(this.cache));
    setTimeout(function() {
      window.mynamespace.cache["foo"] = "bar";
      if(typeof callback == 'function') callback();
    }, 0);
  }
};
window.mynamespace.foo(function(){
  window.mynamespace.foo();
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

A `window.setTimeout` with a `0ms` wait time will clear the calling stack. What's happening is:

CLEARED CALL STACK STATE:

5) key gets set from first foo call setTimeout

6) key gets set from second foo call setTimeout

TOP FRAME OF CALL STACK:

1) foo gets called first

3) second foo call

FOO FRAME OF CALL STACK:

2) first call of foo instantiates cache and alerts empty object

4) second call of foo alerts empty object

Here is a jsfiddle that confirms this behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/jhgeh4c5/1/